# Create Automated Index for huge SQL Server Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a huge SQL Server table with 800mil rows.

It takes about 30gig of disk space without any indexing on it.

What is the best method to apply index in it?

Also this table gets about 50,000 rows inserted every 5 minutes.

There is no delete or update on that table, only `select` for getting results.

Here's what the table looks like:

```
 ID      |           column1             | column2  |   column3   |   column3   |   column4 |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1(PK AI)|'2013-11-04 13:47:03'(datetime)|  A(int)  |    A(char)  |  A(Varchar) | A(Varchar)|
```

Comment: What is an "automated index"? Anyway, one approach that is often overlooked is [Indexed Views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921(v=sql.100).aspx). Also, this question may be more appropriate for the DBA stack.

Comment: What kind of **queries** do you run against this? What columns do you retrieve, what conditions do you have in the `WHERE` clause of your queries?

Comment: sorry about late respond , @user2864740 its "automated indexing", also i moved this to dba section.

Comment: @marc_s , there is lots of query and all of them have "where". these query gets the result in period of time like weekly record , or monthly or daily and for result they return all count,sum,or distinct of fields.

Answer (score 0):

You should determine which SELECT queries are executed the most often.

You can then use the Database Engine Tuning Advisor (in Management Studio under Tools) to automatically derive an index based on this SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN Partitioned Table and Index Concepts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

[Designing Partitions to Manage Subsets of Data](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191174%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)